# Java Regex: Why is the non-capturing group captured?

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

I am using this regex in Java:

`^(Mon(?:.?|day)?)(?:[\.,])?$` (This can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/rg3PGl/1))

I want to capture the day followed by an optional `.` or `,`.
In case of the day Monday I want to capture either `Monday` or `Mon`. However, I don't want the optional `.` or `,` to be saved in a capturing group. This only seems to work for "Monday," not for "Mon." (see link).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to capture `Mon,`?

Comment: I suspect you just need [`^(Mon(?:day)?)[.,]?$`](https://regex101.com/r/1kqLCE/1)

Comment: @Pshemo No, I just want to capture `Mon` without the comma

Comment: So `Mon` should be captured even if it has comma after it. In that cases Wiktor's answer seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^(Mon(?:day)?)[.,]?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1kqLCE/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string (omit if you use `.matches()`)
- `(Mon(?:day)?)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `Mon` - a literal substring
  - `(?:day)?` - an optional `day` char sequence
- `[.,]?` - an optional dot or comma
- `$` - end of string  (omit if you use `.matches()`)